# How to find the running total over dates and specified value of a column?

Tags: sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

Below is how my dataset looks like:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6r9J.png

```
CustNumber  Status  Date    Running Total of Days
C100    IN  10/10/2019  
C100    OUT 10/11/2019  1
C100    IN  10/12/2019  
C100    OUT 10/13/2019  1
C100    IN  10/16/2019  
C100    OUT 10/17/2019  1
C100    IN  4/23/2020   
C100    OUT 4/27/2020   
C100    OUT 4/28/2020   
C100    OUT 4/28/2020   5
C100    IN  10/13/2020  
C100    OUT 10/19/2020  6
```

I want to calculate the running total of number of days column every time the value of "Status" column changes from IN to OUT. On 10/10/19, the value was IN. On 10/11/19 the value was OUT. So running total should be 1.

For the same customer again, on 04/23/2019 the value was IN. On 04/28 the value was OUT again. So the running total should be 5, as it was in 'IN' status for 5 days.

How do I go about implementing this query in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.   Also, show the results as a *formatted table* in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would address this as a gaps-and-islands problem. An island starts everytime a "IN" status is seen: we can use a window count of "IN" statuses to identify these groups of "adjacent" records, then date arithmetics:

```
select t.*,
    date - min(date) over(partition by grp) as running_total_of_days
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when status = 'IN' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by custnumber order by date) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

The actual syntax to compute date differences do vary across databases - and you did not tell which one you are using. The above would work in databases that support directly substracting dates (such as Oracle or Postgres); other database have equivalent syntax or functions.

This puts the running total on each and every row. If you just want it on the last "OUT" row per group, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
    case when status = 'OUT' and row_number() over(partition by grp order by date desc) = 1
        then date - min(date) over(partition by grp) 
    end as running_total_of_days
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when status = 'IN' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by custnumber order by date) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot.:)